# How to access /tmp/contrast.log file in openshift?

Tags: jenkins, directory, openshift, tmp, contrast

Integrating Contrast security in deployment . In the openshift website under pod > Logs, it says:
"Contrast not enabled. Check log for details - /tmp/contrast.log"

Where I can find this /tmp/contrast.log file?

I used oc logs -f alis-services-real-estate-765bc9ddc7-zngxc -c copy-contrast in cmd after running oc.exe and logging into oc but it returns nothing.
But that seems not correct because copy-contrast is the name of the contained and not the /tmp/contrast.log.